# How to test performance in android?

Tags: android, performance, debugging

Please tell me the most sensible and correct ways of measuring/layout inflating performance in the android environment.

For example i have `RecyclerView`. And i have 2 or more use case: what parent layout used for item - ConstraintLayout, RelativeLayout? How i check it? 
I can in binding view process and/or inflating process calculate operation time (stop - start time) and save it. When i scroll view, i take result, but i think this method soo bad and not accurate.

What you recommend? Maybe android or another or special instrument for test layout performance?

P.S.: I understand that this extreme savings, I just want to better understand the tools debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole chapter dedicated to this topic on the android developer guides. [See here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html). For this particular case you can use the [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html)